# How do I make my for await loop do everything within its body before moving on to the next line of code in twilio serverless functions?

Tags: twilio, twilio-programmable-chat

I have been working on this problem for a couple of days now, and feel like I'm extremely close to solving the issue. I need to cycle through an object and send a text message to each record in the object before moving on to the next line of code. The code to send works when isolated locally. But I'm having trouble getting it to work in Twilio Functions. All my code appears to work, but the text messages are not sent.

```html
    for await (const contact of allItems) {
      client.messages
      .create({
      body: "Hey " + contact.name + "!" + " " + message,
      messagingServiceSid: messaging_service,
      to: contact.key
      });
    };
    
  // End Send Message to Each Contact
```

I've attached the portion of code I believe I'm having issues with.

What I want to do, is for this piece of code to run completely before moving on to the next few lines and invoking a callback.

Any idea how I could do something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The issue here is that you are not `await`ing the actual result of the asynchronous call. Locally, that doesn't matter, but within Twilio Functions once you call the `callback` function all asynchronous calls that have started are terminated.

To create a loop that makes asynchronous requests and waits for them all to complete you will want to use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) in conjunction with `map`. In your example, it should look like this:

```js
function SendMessages(allItems, message, client, messagingService) {
  const apiRequests = allItems.map((contact) => {
    let usersName = contact.name;
    return client.messages.create({
      body: `Hey ${usersName}! ${message}`,
      messagingServiceSid: messagingService,
      to: contact.key,
    });
  })
  return Promise.all(apiRequests);
}
```

In this function we map over the list contacts returning the promise that is created when we try to send a message. The variable `apiRequests` becomes an array of promises that represent the requests to the API. We can then use this array of promises in `Promise.all`. `Promise.all` will only resolve once all the promises it is passed have resolved (or if a promise rejects).

I recommend you read [my answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69156053/28376) as that brings up some further issues that you might have with this.

Comment: Thankyou. I had a feeling it had something to do with Promises. I ended up taking a detour down the rabbit hole of Twilio Notify trying to solve the problem I'm having. Seems like it would be great, except that I need to bind Name to Number. Going to implement this code and see how it solves my use case. Thanks so much for your helpful reply.

Comment: I noticed that your messages are personalised, so Notify won’t help here. But if you were happy to send the same message to all the contacts, then Notify is a very good option.